# Metal Shader Function that can deal with both RGB and YUV textures

Tags: ios, iphone, graphics, metal, yuv

I'm trying to teach myself the basics of computer graphics on the iPhone and Apple's Metal API. I'm trying to do something pretty basic, but I'm getting a little stuck.

What I want to do is just "texture a quad". Basically, I make a rectangle and I have an image texture that covers the rectangle. I can make that work for the basic case where the image texture just comes from an image of a known format, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make my code a little more generic and able to handle different formats.

For example, sometimes the image texture comes from an image file, which after decoding it, the pixel data is in the RGB format. Sometimes, my image texture actually comes from a video frame where the data is stored in the YUV format.

Ideally, I'd want to create some sort of "sampler" object or function that can just hand me back an RGB color for a particular texture coordinate. In the code where I prepare for rendering, that's the part with context on which format is getting used, and so it would have enough information to figure out which type of sampler should get used. For example, in the video frame case, it knows that it's working with a video frame and so it creates a YUV sampler and passes it the relevant data. And then from my shader code that just wants to read colors, it can just ask for the color at some particular coordinates, and the YUV sampler would do the proper work to compute the right RGB color. If I passed in an RGB sampler instead, it would just read the RGB data without doing any sort of calculations.

I thought this would be really simple to do? I feel like this has to be a common problem for graphics code that deals with textures in different formats, or colorspaces, or whatever? Am I missing something obvious?

How do you do this without writing a bunch of versions of all of your shaders?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Accelerate's Conversion functions? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/conversion  YCbCr is a supported format using `vImageConvert_AnyToAny()`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1399134-vimageconvert_anytoany

Comment: @JeshuaLacock - Would that require making a copy of the image buffer? Ideally, I want to be able to do that without allocating more memory and putting all the new pixel values in the new memory. If possible, I'd want something that could do it on the fly. Like, as a I request the color for a certain location, the conversion happens for just that color?

Comment: What I was suggesting would be done in pre-processing. If you want to change color spaces on-the-fly, you would just need to implement color space conversion functions. I do this in my own shaders changing RGB to HSL, adjust, then back to RGB.

Answer (score 2):

Here are functions for transforming RGBA to YUVA and vice versa on the fly.

```
float4 rgba2yuva(float4 rgba)
{

    float4 yuva = float4(0.0);

    yuva.x = rgba.r * 0.299 + rgba.g * 0.587 + rgba.b * 0.114;
    yuva.y = rgba.r * -0.169 + rgba.g * -0.331 + rgba.b * 0.5 + 0.5;
    yuva.z = rgba.r * 0.5 + rgba.g * -0.419 + rgba.b * -0.081 + 0.5;
    yuva.w = rgba.a;

    return yuva;
}

float4 yuva2rgba(float4 yuva)
{

    float4 rgba = float4(0.0);

    rgba.r = yuva.x * 1.0 + yuva.y * 0.0 + yuva.z * 1.4;
    rgba.g = yuva.x * 1.0 + yuva.y * -0.343 + yuva.z * -0.711;
    rgba.b = yuva.x * 1.0 + yuva.y * 1.765 + yuva.z * 0.0;
    rgba.a = yuva.a;

    return rgba;
}
```

I adapted the code from here: https://github.com/libretro/glsl-shaders/blob/master/nnedi3/shaders/

Simple OpenGL shaders are quite straightforward to port to Metal. I pretty much just changed the datatype `vec4` to `float4`. If you want a half version, just substitute `float4` for `half4`.

Comment: So, this looks pretty good for converting things on the fly, but it also implies that the code that uses these functions knows about the format of the color? We need to add some sort of if statement after reading a color value out of the texture. I was wondering if there was a way to abstract that so that functions can read colors without needing the conditional logic.

Using your functions, the code uses those helper functions would look something like this.

```
float4 color = texture.sample(sampler, uv);
color = (isYUV ? yuva2rgba(color) color);
```

Comment: I would not be concerned with a simple comparison slowing Metal down to make it even slightly significant. But, if you do not want to do a logic check every draw, you could have two shader calls, one for RGB values and another for YUV. For abstraction, of course you may also write a function with a switch handling all the color space color conversions that you want to support.

Comment: Ya, adding an if statement maybe isn't that big of a deal, but you still have to pass enough metadata to every single thing that needs to read a color so that it knows which version of the helper function to call? Like, you have to pass an RGB texture and a luma/chroma texture to your fragment shader so that it can do both branches?

It seems like this problem could get really out of hand as your code gets more complicated, and it would get worse if you also had to deal with different color spaces and transfer functions in addition to different color models?

Comment: You are responsible for knowing what color space you're working on. There is no magical just give it an image and it knows what color space it is in or anything like that for Metal. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want a separate shader for each type of texture color space then yes, you would pass a different texture based on what the shader is expecting. If you just want to convert color spaces on the fly, then no, just feed it an RGB or whatever your base working color space is.

Answer (score 1):

metal shader function ARK, now you can use @Jeshua Lacock to convert between the two.

```
// tweak your color offsets as desired
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void YUVColorConversion(texture2d<uint, access::read> yTexture [[texture(0)]],
                               texture2d<uint, access::read> uTexture [[texture(1)]],
                               texture2d<uint, access::read> vTexture [[texture(2)]],
                               texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(3)]],
                               uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    float3 colorOffset = float3(0, -0.5, -0.5);
    float3x3 colorMatrix = float3x3(
                                    float3(1, 1, 1),
                                    float3(0, -0.344, 1.770),
                                    float3(1.403, -0.714, 0)
                                    );

    uint2 uvCoords = uint2(gid.x / 2, gid.y / 2);
    
    float y = yTexture.read(gid).r / 255.0;
    float u = uTexture.read(uvCoords).r / 255.0;
    float v = vTexture.read(uvCoords).r / 255.0;

    float3 yuv = float3(y, u, v);

    float3 rgb = colorMatrix * (yuv + colorOffset);

    outTexture.write(float4(float3(rgb), 1.0), gid);
}
```

---

Good ref [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/sample-code/) , and then you can build pipelines or variants for processing specifically what you need like [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/using_function_specialization_to_build_pipeline_variants)

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
#include <simd/simd.h>
#include <metal_texture>
#include <metal_matrix>
#include <metal_geometric>
#include <metal_math>
#include <metal_graphics>
#include "AAPLShaderTypes.h"

using namespace metal;

// Variables in constant address space.
constant float3 lightPosition = float3(0.0, 1.0, -1.0);

// Per-vertex input structure
struct VertexInput {
    float3 position [[attribute(AAPLVertexAttributePosition)]];
    float3 normal   [[attribute(AAPLVertexAttributeNormal)]];
    half2  texcoord [[attribute(AAPLVertexAttributeTexcoord)]];
};

// Per-vertex output and per-fragment input
typedef struct {
    float4 position [[position]];
    half2  texcoord;
    half4  color;
} ShaderInOut;

// Vertex shader function
vertex ShaderInOut vertexLight(VertexInput in [[stage_in]],
                               constant AAPLFrameUniforms& frameUniforms [[ buffer(AAPLFrameUniformBuffer) ]],
                               constant AAPLMaterialUniforms& materialUniforms [[ buffer(AAPLMaterialUniformBuffer) ]]) {
    ShaderInOut out;
    
    // Vertex projection and translation
    float4 in_position = float4(in.position, 1.0);
    out.position = frameUniforms.projectionView * in_position;
    
    // Per vertex lighting calculations
    float4 eye_normal = normalize(frameUniforms.normal * float4(in.normal, 0.0));
    float n_dot_l = dot(eye_normal.rgb, normalize(lightPosition));
    n_dot_l = fmax(0.0, n_dot_l);
    out.color = half4(materialUniforms.emissiveColor + n_dot_l);

    // Pass through texture coordinate
    out.texcoord = in.texcoord;
    
    return out;
}

// Fragment shader function
fragment half4 fragmentLight(ShaderInOut in [[stage_in]],
                             texture2d<half>  diffuseTexture [[ texture(AAPLDiffuseTextureIndex) ]]) {
    constexpr sampler defaultSampler;
    
    // Blend texture color with input color and output to framebuffer
    half4 color =  diffuseTexture.sample(defaultSampler, float2(in.texcoord)) * in.color;
    
    return color;
}
```